# Interfaces covariance problem

Tags: c#, .net, covariance

So i have such code.

```
public interface IGeoDataSet<out T> : IDataSet
    where T : IGeoPrimitive<IGeoPrimitiveContent>
{
    IEnumerable<T> Items { get; } 
}

public interface IDataSet { }

public interface IGeoPrimitive<T> : IPrimitive
    where T : IGeoPrimitiveContent
{
    T Content { get; }
}

public interface IPrimitive { }

public interface IGeoPrimitiveContent { }
```

And such inplementation for previous interfaces.

```
public class TriangleDataSet : IGeoDataSet<Triangle>
{
    public IEnumerable<Triangle> Items { get; private set; }
}

public class Triangle : IGeoPrimitive<TriangleContent>
{
    public TriangleContent Content { get; private set; }
}

public class TriangleContent : IGeoPrimitiveContent { }
```

When I try to compile this code I've got an error:

```
The type '.Triangle' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method '.IGeoDataSet<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from '.Triangle' to '.IGeoPrimitive<.IGeoPrimitiveContent>'.
```

I can't understand why, maybe someone knows what is the problem?

Br,
Jevgenij

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need for your `IGeoPrimitive<T>` interface to *also* be covariant in order to be able to use `Triangle` as the type parameter for a `IGeoDataSet<out T>` implementation:

```
// Note addition of 'out' keyword
public interface IGeoPrimitive<out T> : IPrimitive
    where T : IGeoPrimitiveContent
{
    T Content { get; }
}
```

This is because you have a `where T : IGeoPrimitive<IGeoPrimitiveContent>` constraint; but without `IGeoPrimitive<T>` being covariant, a `Triangle` (which implements `IGeoPrimitive<TriangleContent>`) does **not** meet this constraint.

Comment: yeap, it works, thanx :) but one more question, for example, i want to use ObservableCollection in IGeoDataSet for Items collection insted of IEnumerable? is it possible? when i've tried this i've got an error.

Comment: @Jevgenij: No, I don't believe that will be possible, because `ObservableCollection<T>` is not covariant like `IEnumerable<T>`. This is because it has methods that take `T` as a parameter; for example, `Add`. If you tried to make this covariant you might have, say, a `TriangleDataSet`, cast it to an `IGeoDataSet<IGeoPrimitive<IGeoPrimitiveContent>>`, and then call `Items.Add(new Pentagon())`, which would clearly be illegal for a `TriangleDataSet`. Does that make sense?

Comment: yeap, thanks :) but i do not understand your idea about private set accessor in Triangle type, i works fine with this accessor too.

Comment: @Jevgenij: Yeah, I wasn't thinking straight; since the `set` is private, it really doesn't affect the type's covariance. I'll remove that part from my answer as it is just flat-out incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `IGeoPrimitive<T>` covariant:

```
public interface IGeoPrimitive<out T> : IPrimitive
    where T : IGeoPrimitiveContent
{
    T Content { get; }
}
```

Comment: I've already try this solution, when I try to declare IGeoPrimitive<in T> covariant, I've got an error.

Comment: yeah, that's because it's the opposite - contravariant.

Comment: Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be covariantly valid on '.IGeoPrimitive<T>.Content'. 'T' is contravariant.

Comment: @Femaref: You've got it backwards. It needs to be `IGeoPrimitive<out T>` (as you have it), which is **covariant**.

Comment: Nope, the definition is contravariant, but it's covariant to IGeoPrimitive.

Comment: @Femaref: What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Are you better off declaring your interfaces as:

```
public interface IGeoDataSet<out T, out V> : IDataSet
    where T : IGeoPrimitive<V>
    where V : IGeoPrimitiveContent
{
    IEnumerable<T> Items { get; } 
}
```

and

```
public interface IGeoPrimitive<out T> : IPrimitive
    where T : IGeoPrimitiveContent
{
    T Content { get; }
}
```